# Java key codes don't match between OS's or computers

Tags: java, awt, keyevent

The key codes I get for characters such as ` and / on Windows (or at least on my Windows machine) is different on my laptop with Ubuntu.

I use KeyEvent.getKeyCode() to get the key code and java.awt.Robot.keyPress() to get the key however it's not the same or it gives an invalid key code exception.

My code is as simple as

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    code = e.getKeyCode();
}
```

on the Windows machine and

```
bot.keyPress(code);
```

on the Ubuntu machine.

I need to make the keys pressed match. How can I do this?

Comment: Many laptops allow keys to have "extended" functionality (meaning you need to press the FN key, for example). The keyboard driver may also be mapping physical keys to different virtual keys

Comment: I have a laptop with a ` and / key though. It's just that the key codes for them are different. Other keys such as numbers, letters and keys like Enter, Backspace, Home etc are fine however.

Comment: So, it's the keyboard drivers responsibility to take a physical key and map it to virtual key

Comment: So how can I get it to compare the key character instead of the key code then? There is no getKeyCode(String).

Comment: Are you looking for `e.getKeyChar()`?

Comment: I don't think so, I need the shift and enter keys to work too.